# TFS SDK : Get Child Branches

Tags: tfs-sdk

What I want to do is to get the available branches that I can merge to. Pretty much the same as the dropdown when you say merge in TFS2008 and you select the destination branch.

However, it's been very hard to find how.

Below code is a merge between some of the resources I've found in the web, but none seem to work. My guess is that if VS2008 can do it, I can do it thru the SDK, right?.

The below code always give me the same result all the time.

My repository is something like this:

```
Development
  Version1
    Code
  Version2
    Code
  Version3
    Code
Main
  Code
```

And normally I branch Main > Version X. So the merging can be done Main > Version X and Version X to Main.

The below code always gives me the children of the Main, even if I'm querying (tfsParentBranchPath) with Version3 folder.

Is this because perhaps I used TFS2010 web service but pointing to TFS2008 (that's why I marked some methods that do not work in the code)?

Well please let me know, if someone knows the answer.

Thanks!

```
 public string[] GetChildBranchesToMerge(string tfsParentBranchPath)
    {
    var versionControl = teamFoundationServer.GetService<VersionControlServer>();

    //not supported by tfs2008
    //ItemIdentifier[] identifiers = versionControl.QueryMergeRelationships(tfsParentBranchPath);
    //var allBranches = versionControl.QueryBranchObjects(new ItemIdentifier(tfsParentBranchPath), RecursionType.OneLevel);

    List<string> childs = new List<string>();
    ItemSpec[] specs = new ItemSpec[] { new ItemSpec(tfsParentBranchPath, RecursionType.OneLevel) };
    BranchHistoryTreeItem[][] branchHistoryTree = versionControl.GetBranchHistory(specs, VersionSpec.Latest);

    if (branchHistoryTree.Length > 0 && branchHistoryTree[0].Length > 0)
    {
        var treeItem = branchHistoryTree[0][0];

        if (treeItem.Children.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (BranchHistoryTreeItem tia in treeItem.Children)
            {
                childs.Add(tia.Relative.BranchToItem.ServerItem);
            }
        }
    }

    return childs.OrderBy((s) =>
    {
        return s;
    }).ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, this is the last version that works!.

First, I stopped using VS2010 assemblies and it's much faster now.

Second, the big difference is this line:

```
var treeItem = branchHistoryTree[0][0].GetRequestedItem();
```

I really dont know why the difference, but it seems without that method, the item returned is a generic one.

```
public string[] GetChildBranchesToMerge(string tfsParentBranchPath)
{
    DoLog("Getting child branches for {0} ...", tfsParentBranchPath);
    VersionControlServer vcs = (VersionControlServer)teamFoundationServer.GetService(typeof(VersionControlServer));

    List<string> childs = new List<string>();
    ItemSpec[] specs = new ItemSpec[] { new ItemSpec(tfsParentBranchPath, RecursionType.OneLevel) };
    BranchHistoryTreeItem[][] branchHistoryTree = vcs.GetBranchHistory(specs, VersionSpec.Latest);

    if (branchHistoryTree.Length > 0 && branchHistoryTree[0].Length > 0)
    {
        var treeItem = branchHistoryTree[0][0].GetRequestedItem();
        AddChildBranch(childs, treeItem, tfsParentBranchPath);

        if (treeItem.Children != null && treeItem.Children.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (BranchHistoryTreeItem tia in treeItem.Children)
            {
                AddChildBranch(childs, tia, tfsParentBranchPath);
            }
        }
    }

    DoLog("{0} child branches found", childs.Count);

    return childs.OrderBy((s) =>
    {
        return s;
    }).ToArray();
}

private void AddChildBranch(List<string> list, BranchHistoryTreeItem itemToCheck, string tfsParentBranchPath)
{
    if (itemToCheck.Relative.BranchFromItem != null && itemToCheck.Relative.BranchFromItem.DeletionId == 0 && itemToCheck.Relative.BranchFromItem.ServerItem != tfsParentBranchPath)
        list.Add(itemToCheck.Relative.BranchFromItem.ServerItem);

    if (itemToCheck.Relative.BranchToItem != null && itemToCheck.Relative.BranchToItem.DeletionId == 0 && itemToCheck.Relative.BranchToItem.ServerItem != tfsParentBranchPath)
        list.Add(itemToCheck.Relative.BranchToItem.ServerItem);
}
```